# Ratio of $(\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A})$ largest eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose $\mathbf{A}$ is a $n\times 3$ matrix where each column has values in a defined range, i.e. 
$$b_{1min} < a_{1i} < b_{1max}, $$
$$b_{2min} < a_{2i} < b_{2max}, $$
$$b_{3min} < a_{3i} < b_{3max}, $$
Is there a way to reason about the ratio of the two largest eigenvalues of the SSCP matrix of $\mathbf{A}$:
$$
\rho = \frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}
$$
Where $\lambda_i$ are the ordered eigenvalues of $(\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A})^{-1}$

I tried messing about with the trace, since the diagonal of the SSCP is the squared norms of $\mathbf{A}$'s columns, but got nowhere. I didn't figure out a way to get rid of $\lambda_3$ to somehow form the desired ratio.
Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps much, but you can put a definite upper bound on this ratio. Supposing $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$, and $\lambda_3$ are the ordered eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}^{T}\mathbf{A}$ then $( \kappa (\mathbf{A}))^{2} =\frac{\lambda _{1}}{\lambda _{3}} \ $ where $\kappa (\mathbf{A}) =\| \mathbf{A} \| _{2} \| \mathbf{A}^{-1} \| _{2} \ $. So $\frac{\lambda _{1}}{\lambda _{2}}$ is definitely no larger than $\sqrt{\kappa (\mathbf{A})}$.

Comment: @K.defaoite Thanks, how did you arrive to the relationship about $k(\mathbf{A})^2$?

Comment: Also, $\mathbf{A}$ is not always invertible

Comment: $\kappa (\mathbf{A})$ is the condition number of the matrix. The Wikipedia page on it is pretty good : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number#Matrices